# how to authenticate by Token in cakephp2 with BzUtils plugin.?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

**I use plugin BzUtils plugin create token for authenticate.
file boostrapt:**

CakePlugin::load('BzUtils ');

**file AppController:**

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ),
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'scope' => array(
                    'User.active' => 1,
                )
            ),
            'BzUtils.JwtToken' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password',
                ),
                'header' => 'AuthToken',
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'scope' => array(
                    'User.active' => 1
                )
            )
        );
```

**And action login in RestUsersController :**

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $user = $this->Auth->user();
            $token = JWT::encode($user, Configure::read('Security.salt'));
            $this->set('user', $user);
            $this->set('token', $token);
            $this->set('_serialize', array('user', 'token'));
        } else {
            throw new NotAcceptableException(__('Email or password is wrong.'));
        }
    }
```

**Url : http://kcxcode1.dev/restusers/login**

Error : Fatal error: Class 'JWT' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\koreconx\app\Controller\RestUsersController.php on line 42

Comment: Is this the plugin you are using? https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-bz-utils

Comment: plugin I using : https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-bz-utils/tree/develop

Comment: Yea I found the branch that is different. In this plugin/branch where is the static function `encode`? Can you find it and link it here?

Comment: I don't understand.. Help me fix error..I doing code api restful webservie with cakephp2 but I can not using any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

> Error : Fatal error: Class 'JWT' not found in

The error is pretty obvious.
You need the [php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) lib that is used within the adapter. Add it via composer or manually add it.

```
composer require firebase/php-jwt
```

I've updated the plugins composer.json with that depedency but only *suggest* it there. Also I've updated the readme.md, added the adapter there and a link to an article about it. And I've merged develop to master as well.

It looks like you're using [my article](http://florian-kraemer.net/2014/07/cakephp-and-token-based-auth-with-angular-js/), it mentions in the 2nd paragraph that php-jwt is needed and even links to it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will trying again. JWT have support cakephp2 ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. JWT has nothing to do with Cake, the lib is a stand alone lib and works with any other framework. They don't have hard depedencies on each other.

Comment: Cakephp 2 not supprt load vendor ...heyz.

Comment: That's **not** true. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html and if you can't use composer (I can't think of a reason) then use App::import().

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you, I mistake                                                                          `Declaration of JwtTokenAuthenticate::getUser() should be compatible with BaseAuthenticate::getUser($request) [APP\Plugin\BzUtils\Controller\Component\Auth\JwtTokenAuthenticate.php, line 123]`

Comment: This is not a forum, please update your question or ask a new question of it is a different problem. This is not an answer. Also I don't understand the meaning of this. The signatures match. See http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/source-class-BaseAuthenticate.html#215

Comment: I concur with the op I had exactly the same issue. Although the article **does*** have links to the jwt-php library there is no explanation or example of how to include it in a Cake App. The article and examples do not provide full steps (as stated) which means trying to piece bits of code together from various sources which is shame because this looks like an elegant solution.